# Find average of a variable from 2 different datatable with the same date and time

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```vb
For i As Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
Dim temp1 As Integer = table.Rows(i)("Temperature")
Dim temp2 As Integer = table2.Rows(i)("Temperature")
Dim date1 As DateTime = table.Rows(i)("Date Time")
Dim date2 As DateTime = table2.Rows(i)("Date Time")
table.Rows(i)("Temperature") = (table.Rows(i)("Temperature") + table2.Rows(i)("Temperature")) / 2
Next
```

```
sensor  Temperature Humidity    Date Time   sensor  Temperature Humidity    Date Time
a   22.6    69.3    2020-08-12 0:04:22  b   23  55.7    2020-08-12 0:02:42
a   22.6    69.3    2020-08-12 0:29:23  b   22.9    55.3    2020-08-12 0:27:43
a   22.5    69.2    2020-08-12 0:59:24  b   22.6    55.5    2020-08-12 0:57:54
a   22.5    69.2    2020-08-12 1:29:26  b   23  55.2    2020-08-12 1:27:54
a   22.2    68.9    2020-08-12 5:02:02  b   23  55.6    2020-08-12 1:57:56
a   22.4    68.8    2020-08-12 7:33:44  b   23  54.5    2020-08-12 2:27:57
```

This is my code to get all the temperature values and date time values from both table and get the average.The datetime value can be round to nearest xx:00 or xx:30 but how do i get the average of the same datetime because they could be missing datetime as u can see from the data above.Using a for loop with i would just give me average of different datetime values. Edit: Please do not give any answers related to the sql statement as the original statement to retrieve the above results is already very complicated and its just not possible to do it with sql statement in my case.

Comment: Does "nearest xx:00 or xx:30" mean to the nearest 30 seconds or the nearest half hour?

Comment: @AndrewMorton nearest half hour

Answer (score 0):

I would move the calculation to T-SQL and use a GROUP BY on a UNION ALL of the two tables. The GROUP BY has to be on a value or values that give you the desired time slots. For time slots that don't fit an existing function, an expression is required.  In this case it's a little more tricky because you want to round to the nearest half minute.

I get the seconds since midnight.  I add 15 seconds to round up the prior 15 seconds.  I divided by 30 to truncate the half minute.  Multiple by 30 to get seconds.  This is the value to add back to midnight.  "sample_time" is your "Date Time".  (Some would use 0 rather than the date part, but for seconds this will overflow.)

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD(s, 
        (15+DATEDIFF(s, CAST(CAST(sample_time as date) as datetime), sample_time))/30 * 30, 
        CAST(CAST(sample_time as date) as datetime)
        ) as [TimeSlot],
    AVG(Temperture) as [TemperatureAvg]
FROM (
    SELECT sample_time, temperature
    FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT sample_time, temperature
    FROM table2
)
GROUP BY DATEADD(s, 
    (15+DATEDIFF(s, CAST(CAST(sample_time as date) as datetime), sample_time))/30 * 30, 
    CAST(CAST(sample_time as date) as datetime)
    )
```

If you need a table of all time slots, the GROUP BY is not enough as you note.  Use a "numbers table" (there should be plenty online about this) to generate the times you want.  You can put it in a CTE, temp table, local table, or derived table.  (If you want a single query, then a CTE or derived table is the way to go.)  Then use a left join to this table with the real data on TimeSlot.  Decide how to display the null data using ISNULL or such.

For example, if you wanted 24 hours of data, you need numbers from 0 to 24 * 60 * 2 (2 slots per minute for 24 hours).  Use 24 * 60 * 2 - 1 if the last point is not to be included.  If the numbers table generator has more numbers than you need (normal for some efficient methods), use a WHERE clause to get just the range you need.  Given a start date, the DATEADD function can be used to set a time column for the slot.  Maybe something like DATEADD(second, @startdate, [num] * 30).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to come up with this answer, unfortunately i cannot do this with the sql way as the original sql statement to retrieve the data is already very complicated and its just not possible to do it with the sql statement for my case. I should have mentioned it in the post sorry.